# Interval of Convergence $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)}$ has the Maclaurin series:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n$$
Find the Interval of Convergence

I've gotten to $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{(-x)^n} \right\rvert$$

Unsure where to go from here.
I've viewed a few other threads and youtube videos but none seemed to help my case.

Comment: What do you require about that limit to guarantee convergence of the series?

Comment: Question states it converges( doesn't ask for proof ) its just a question from First year maths

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Edited to exactly what my professor asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For what values of $r$ can you conclude that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
edit: this is circular after OP edited in what professor asked.

By the ratio test, which you started doing, you need 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{(-x)^n}|<1\Rightarrow 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|-x|<1\Rightarrow |x|<1
$$

Answer (score 0):

For your computation...

First you need to understand
$$
\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{(-x)^n} = (-x)
$$
When you see this left-hand-side, you should automatically know to convert it to the right-hand-side.

Since you did not do that, my guess is: you need to review your algebra before you take calculus.